# Carrierwave dynamic storage type via model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, gridfs, fog

I want to save photographs in 'grid_fs' and other types of files into 'fog', like:

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def storage
    if model.is_photograph == true
      :grid_fs
    else
      :fog
    end 
  end
end
```

Is this possible?

I want to dynamically assign the storage type from model attributes, and I've
tried [this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Dynamically-set-storage-type), but the model and its attributes are not accessible in a class method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is "no". Unlike `store_dir`, `validate_integrity` et al, [storage](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb#L71) isn't sent through `add_config`, and doesn't get any of the [instance-level magic](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb#L105) that would make this easy.

It might be possible, but anything I could come up with almost certainly be a fragile hack. You're better off looking at other ways to support the feature (multiple uploaders?) or changing the specification.